# Opportunistic caching with reusable custom graphs in Dask

Tags: python, caching, dask

[Dask](https://github.com/dask/dask) supports defining [custom computational graphs](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/custom-graphs.html) as well as [opportinistic caching](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/caching.html). The question is how can they be used together.

For instance, let's define a very simple computational graph, that computes `x+1` operation,

```
import dask

def compute(x):
    graph = {'step1': (sum, [x, 1])}
    return dask.get(graph, 'step1')

print('Cache disabled:', compute(1), compute(2))
```

this yields `2` and `3` as expected.

Now we enable opportunistic caching,

```
from dask.cache import Cache

cc = Cache(1e9)
cc.register()

print('Cache enabled: ', compute(1), compute(2))
print(cc.cache.data)
```

we get incorrectly a result of `2` in both cases, because `cc.cache.data` is `{'step1': 2}` irrespective of the input.

I imagine this means that the input needs to be hashed (e.g. with [`dask.base.tokenize`](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/d80957501680522291de0653f3d9e2eda010295e/dask/base.py#L511-L522) and appended to all the keys in the graph. Is there a simpler way of doing it, particularly since [the tokenize function is not part of the public API](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/593)?

The issue is that in complex graphs, a random step name, needs to account for the hash of all the inputs provided to it's children steps, which means that it's necessary to do full graph resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important that key names in dask graphs are unique (as you found above). Additionally, we'd like identical computations to have the same key so we can avoid computing them multiple times - this isn't necessary for dask to work though, it just provides some opportunities for optimization.

In dask's internals we make use of [`dask.base.tokenize`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/custom-collections.html#implementing-deterministic-hashing) to compute a "hash" of the inputs, resulting in deterministic key names. You are free to make use of this function as well. In the issue you linked above we say the function is public, just that the implementation might change (not the signature).

Also note that for many use cases, we recommend using [`dask.delayed`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed-overview.html) now instead of custom graphs for generating custom computations. This will do the deterministic hashing for you behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations.